# Fonts in message area too small to read in Thunderbird

Tags: fonts, email, thunderbird

I use Thunderbird as my email client.  For some reason fonts in the message area are so small that they are unreadable. This includes the Thunderbird welcome screen font.

Comment: Could you, or anyone else reading this, add a screenshot to give people an idea of what this problem looks like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Edit-Preferences->Display->Advanced and then change the Minimum Font Size to something bigger than 10 (depends on how big you like them to be)

This worked on my system.

Comment: hey! that actually worked! i thought I'd tried it already but i guess not. thanks :)

Comment: Is this still up-to-date?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `Edit->Preferences->Display` and change default font,font size there

Comment: yeah tried that already didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> on the message as many times as needed to zoom in on the text.

Answer (score 1):

There's many fonts in `Edit->Preferences->Display`, 
you should setup fonts size for each type you're using (**unicode, western, cyrillic etc.**)